# jQuery box open/close functions with toggle animates

Tags: jquery

I have this jquery function. I need a toggle function to open and close the div boxes. But at the same time i need it to close all open div boxes with an animation, and then open the one you have clicked on.

JS:

```
function showAndHidediv(id) {
$("#" + id).slideToggle();
}
```

HTML:

```
<a onclick="showAndHidediv('test');">Open 1</a>    
<a onclick="showAndHidediv('test2');">Open 2</a>    
<a onclick="showAndHidediv('test3');">Open 3</a>

<div id="test" class="accordionBox">Test 1</div>
<div id="test2" class="accordionBox">Test 2</div>
<div id="test3" class="accordionBox">Test 3</div>
```

CSS:

```
.accordionBox {
    width: 100%!important;
    display: none;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #119df2;
}
```

JS fiddle:

[JS fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/rdm3Lumk/38/)

Comment: Like this https://jqueryui.com/accordion/?

Comment: @user3661240 i updated my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should avoid a onclick and other inline attribute in html.
Solution for your problem:

```
<a href="#" data-tab-id="test1" class="open-box">Open 1</a>
<a href="#" data-tab-id="test2" class="open-box">Open 2</a>
<a href="#" data-tab-id="test3" class="open-box">Open 3</a>

<div id="test1" class="accordionBox">Test 1</div>
<div id="test2" class="accordionBox">Test 2</div>
<div id="test3" class="accordionBox">Test 3</div>
```

And JS:

```
$('.open-box').click(function() {

    var box =  $('#' + $(this).attr('data-tab-id'));

    if(box.is(":visible")){
        box.toggle(500);
        return;
    }

    var visibleBoxes = $('.accordionBox:visible')
    if (visibleBoxes.length > 0) {
        $('.accordionBox:visible').toggle(500);

    }

    box.toggle(500);
});
```

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0zextx9t/7/

Comment: Thats exactly what i want, but i also want it to have a "toggle" function, so when you click open 2 second time it closes the box, how do I do that?

Comment: That is spot on! Thank you very much!